# Handle GitHub matrix output in next job

Tags: github, github-actions

There are two jobs in below GitHub workflow. First job is using matrix strategy which will have three parallel jobs running. then next job will wait for first job and print the output of matrix job.

The problem is all the jobs from matrix are returning some output which is stored in one variable `prodApp`. This is getting overwritten by the job which will get executed last from the matrix.

Is there any way to store the output of all the jobs from matrix ? I have tried by giving the dynamic variable name which is not supported in GitHub workflow.

```
jobs:
  matrixJob:
    outputs:
     prodApp: ${{ steps.job.outputs.prod }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        job-index: [prod1, prod2, prod3]

    steps:
      - name: Run Job
        id: job
        run: |
          echo "prod=${{matrix.job-index}}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"


  printResults:
    needs: [matrixJob]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      
      - name: print
        run: |
         echo "${{needs.matrixJob.outputs.prodApp}}"
```

workflow for reference:
[image]

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/17245?